# iteration over nested lists

Tags: python, loops, nested-lists

I have a game field (board size is min 1x1, max 10x10)
which is represented by a nested list i.e. `[['-', '-'], ['-', '-']]` where `'-'` means the cell is empty and every list represents a row.
I can put ships there, for ex `[['a', '-'], ['a', '-']]` means that there is a ship `'a'` of size 2 that stand vertically in column 0.

I need to write a code that will make sure that the ship appears only once. For example, the following is an **invalid** layout:

```
[['a', '-', 'a'],
 ['a', '-', '-'],
 ['-', '-', '-']]
```

I understand that it will turn out to be a loop, but I have no idea where to start.

Comment: What is your question? This sounds like you want someone to do your assignment question.

Comment: how do I make it check over the nested list
I understand that once [cell] = '-' whereas around it there are other strings,
it means that the ship doesn t appear once

Answer (score 0):

```
nested = [['nested', 'list'], ['2nd', 'row']]

for row in nested:
    for item in row:
        print item
```

You are now looping over a nested list.  Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Since this looks like homework, I'll give you a starting point, but you'll need to expand on this.

For a gameboard (or any matrix really) you'll want two `for` loops. One for the x-axis and one for the y-axis. Assuming you're using a 2d array:

```
#loop over all rows
for row in array:
    #loop over all columns
    for column in row:
        #process each cell here
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's say your board is 3x3, invalid board.

```
my_board_rows = [['a', 'a', '-'],
                 ['-', 'a', '-'],
                 ['-', 'a', '-']]

my_board_cols = [[col[i] for col in my_board] for i in range(len(my_board))]
```

You can just check for extraneous `a`'s using `for` loops.

```
row_idx = []
for row, items in enumerate(my_board_rows):
    for item in range(len(items)):
        if items[item] == 'a':
            row_idx.append([row, item])
if len(dict(row_idx)) > 1:
    print('Invalid board!')
```

And the same for columns:

```
col_idx = []
for col, items in enumerate(my_board_cols):
    for item in range(len(items)):
        if items[item] == 'a':
            idx.append([col, item])
if len(dict(col_idx)) > 1:
    print('Invalid board!')
```

This will print `Invalid board!` when looping through the rows.